# Как правильно: "согласно расписания" или "согласно расписанию"?

Tags: согласование

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка-то - она ошибка, но у неё есть вполне основательная причина. Ещё в XIX веке употребление родительного падежа было нормативным. Почему-то у нас это сейчас очень редко вспоминают, полагая такую форму вопиющей безграмотностью.

Comment: Так большинство так и говорит-пишет во вполне уважаемых и официальных изданиях, учреждениях: согласно приказа... Наоборот (то, что правильно) встречаю редко. Если бы не специальность... и не заметила бы ошибку.

Comment: Я же не возражаю, что это ошибка, причем грубая. Но не стоит постоянно возмущаться тем, что имеет логичное объяснение.

Comment: Соглашусь, что неоднократно видел в официальных документах "согласно" + род. падеж. Глаз режет весьма сильно.

Comment: "Ещё в XIX веке употребление родительного падежа было нормативным" - исключительно в канцеляризмах. В литературной речи, думаю, такого не найдёте.

Comment: Думаю, что найду без особых проблем. XIX век - это не только Чехов, но еще и Державин. Только сейчас мне лениво, попозже.

Comment: неизвестный. Вегетарианствующая Одесса (1912.06.18) // «Одесский листок», 1912   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1)

    **Главнейшая задача о-ва, согласно его устава** ― содействовать распространенно безубойного питания ― фруктами, овощами, зерновыми хлебами и другими произведениями растительного царства, вместо питания мясом убитых животных. [неизвестный. Вегетарианствующая Одесса (1912.06.18) // «Одесский листок», 1912] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

Answer (score 6):

Предлоги *согласно, вопреки, благодаря* употребляются с дательным падежом. *Согласно (кому? чему?) расписани**ю**.* Употребление с родительным падежом - очень распространенная ошибка.